# Undefined control sequence blx@rlm@\english

Tags: biblatex

I want to create publication lists for several authors. These lists are grouped by an arbitrary property that we store in the annote field. To filter on these properties, I have a base file for each author that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

For each author and each category, we add a

```
\addbibresource{Author1_Books.bib}
\defbibcheck{annoteBooks}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{Books}{}{\skipentry}}
```

to the document's preface and a

```
\printbibliography[title={Books}, check=annoteBooks]
```

to the document's body.

This works fine for one author, but for another author I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> blx@rlm@\english

l.52 ...{Journal Papers}, check=annoteJournalPapers]
```

I have no clue where this error comes from and how to get rid of it.

As it works for one author, but fails for another, I thought that it may be related to the different publications in their list. Thus I removed all publications where the second author is in the authors list, but not the first. Without success.

I'm a little bit helpless, as I even have no idea where this one is coming from.

Comment: Do you maybe have `\english` somewhere where you should have `english` instead? Is there any way you could provide a full MWE that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @moewe Thanks for that hint. I was too blind to see the problem. There actually was a `language = {\english}` somewhere in the bibtex-file. You could add your comment as answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have `\english` in a `language` field where you should have `english` instead.